# Importing visualization function from .py file to use in .ipynb file

Tags: python, python-import

I am new to python and have some problems importing functions from a .py file to use in a .ipynb file..

I am trying to call the following function from my visualization_tb.py file:

```
def treemap_show(df):
    fig = px.treemap(df, path=[df.index], 
                values='Score',title="Country names based on Happiness score")
    return fig.show()
```

In my file .ipynb I have imported the function like this:

```
from utils.visualization_tb import *
```

This works as I have tested it before.
However when calling the function like this in my .ipynb file:

```
treemap_show(complete_data_2015)
```

It does not show me anything. I have also tried to save it as a variable x and then do x.show() but that also doesn't work neither.

How can I use the imported function so that it shows the plot in my .ipynb file?

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? How is the utils file/folder constructed? Are they in the same folder as the `.ipynb` file?

Comment: No, no message at all. it executes the cell, but simply does not do or show anything. the files are not in the same folder. but I have made sure I have done  the 
sys.path.append(root_path). I have also tested it with a simple function that prints "I'm working" and that ones imports from the .py without a problem..

Comment: Try removing `return fig.show()` i.e just call `fig.show()` and then `return 0`

Comment: Just tried it, but it does not work unfortunately..

Comment: If you just put the function in the script, does it work then?

Comment: It seems to have resolved itself, after stopping and restarting the kernel a few times. Very strange. But now with simply fig.show() in the function and calling it from the .ipynb file it shows the graph without a problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this if the function you want to import from the file is in the same directory

.ipynb file:

```
import visualization_tb

visualization_tb.treemap_show(complete_data_2015)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But importing functions from the .py file works good. I have tried to import a simple test function from .py and that one imports and works perfectely in the .ipynb file. Therefor I think there might be a problem with calling on functions to show plots and other visualization tools. Because the function works when putting the code in the .ipynb file and it works to import the functions from the .py file to the .ipynb file, but it just does not show the plot.

Comment: have you tried putting your function into a simple print()?